# ATI HD4xxx driver installation problem on 12.04.3

Tags: installation, drivers, ati

My own computer failed, so I decided to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 on my wife's.
So I downloaded and installed 12.04.3 (64 bits).
I couldn't succeed to install AMD proprietary drivers, neither through the AMD site package (13.1-legacy proposed) nor through the distribution repositories.
Is there a way to install a functional proprietary driver for my card with 12.04.3 ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

is there any chance you can provide some screen logs or other relevant frame of reference / error messages, so that we can help you?

For example, the proprietary driver will log to a file:

```
/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log
```

If you could post errors from there..?

cheers

sc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not home now. It's related to kernel headers but I think it's not the problem. Maybe a problem of unsupported kernel or Xorg ?

Comment: impossible to say other than mere speculation until we see some errno.

Comment: Back home.
Install log :
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.8.0-34-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.

Comment: Hi there - so it looks like you may well need the headers.  Take a look at this link (if you haven't already) [BinaryDriverHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

Comment: The pb is that I do have the headers. It is one of the methods I followed.

Comment: I've tried it again to show the exact error :
fglrx 2:8.960-0ubuntu1.1:fglrx kernel module failed to build
.........
kernel includes at /lib/modules/3.8.0.34-generic/build/include not found or incomplete file :/lib/modules/3.8.0.34-generic/build/include/linux/version.h.

I verified and the file is missing. What should I do ?

Comment: Found it as a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/859101) but it doesn't seem to be solved for 12.04.3. Is there a workaround ?